# Azure Data Factory fails to preview data or import schem from SQL Azure Table

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I get an error when trying to create a Dataset in Azure Data Factory V2 against a table in a SQL Azure database.

The table does have a Geography field, otherwise it's a standard table!! Any ideas?

Error reported is:

'Type=,Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.,Source=,'. Activity ID:52dda22e-6328-40cb-b30a-7255117ac37d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a support call with Microsoft and after verifying the issue, they were surprised that Geography fields caused this failure. 
I have been told that they will be working on a fix and await an update of when this will be applied.

Comment: Apparently Geography is still not supported, but they have now fixed the error message! I have not tested this though. I eventually made a work around.

Comment: In the end I just excluded the geography field from the source. I now can't remember if it was using a query to drop the field or just removing it from the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Geography is currently not supported.

- 1. You could write a query to exclude this column if you don't need data of this column.
- 2. If you want to copy it to another azure sql or sql server as-is, meaning you don't need specify column mapping (column name between source and sink are well matched), you could skip the preview and schema.